# ¿Como ordenar estos if? me dijieron que esta desordenado

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).keypress(function( event ) {

    if(mover)
    {

        switch(event.which)
        {   


            case 119: // W
                if(checkearBloque(posX,posY+1))
                    if(checkearnota(posX,posY+1))
                        if(checkeaArbol(posX,posY+1))
                            if(checkeaPoso(posX,posY+1))
                                if(checkeacasa(posX,posY+1))
                                if(checkeaLago(posX,posY+1))
                                    if(checkearmaria(posX,posY+1))
                                        if(checkearPedro(posX,posY+1))
                                            if(checkearLetrero(posX,posY+1)){{{{ {{{{ {
                    posY++;
                    $("#datos").text("arriba");
                    $( "#pj" ).animate({ "top": "-=20px" }, "fast", function(){
                        mover=true;
                    } );
                }}}} }}}} }


            break;
```

Comment: y cual es la duda? que hace este código? cual es el fallo que muestra?

Comment: Te sugiero que investiges `AND` que en javascript es `&&`

Comment: Nunca había visto tantos `if` juntos. ¿Por qué no usas un objeto estructurado donde comparar. Por ejemplo un array, un JSON o algo así? En el array metes a `bloque, nota, arbol, poso, casa...` con los valores asociados y luego buscas si existe alguna asociación. Si existe, aumentas `posY++` y nada más.

Answer (score 2):

Dado que siempre comparas los mismos valores: `posX` y `posY+1`, puedes tener una función con un objeto que guarde pares de valores. Le pasas `posX` y `posY+1` y la función encontrará si hay coincidencias, devolviendo `true`, o si no hay coincidencias, devolviendo `false`.

En caso de necesidad, el código podría informar en qué elemento hubo coincidencias (ver mensaje del `console.log`.

La comprobación se haría con una llamada así simplemente:

```
if (checkAll(posX,posY+1)){
    posY++;
    $("#datos").text("arriba");
    $( "#pj" ).animate({ "top": "-=20px" }, "fast", function(){
        mover=true;
    } );
}
```

He aquí un código con varias llamadas de ejemplo.

```js
function checkAll(posX, posY) {
  /*
    *Este objeto representa el estado de cada elemento
    *no conozco tu contexto, pero no será difícil construir
    *algo así, incluso de forma dinámica si fuese necesario
  */
  var myObject = {
    'bloque': [1, 2],
    'nota': [3, 4],
    'arbol': [5, 3],
    'poso': [4, -1],
    'casa': [3, 3],
    'lago': [0, 0],
    'maria': [4, 8],
    'pedro': [9, 9],
    'letrero': [-3, -5]
  };
  
  /*Variable para determinar si hubo coincidencias*/
  var isEqual = false;
  for (var k in myObject) {
    var itemPair = myObject[k];
    if (itemPair[0] === posX && itemPair[1] === posY) {
      console.log(`Se encontró coincidencia en ${k}`);
      isEqual = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(isEqual);
  return isEqual;
}

/*Tres ejemplos*/
checkAll(1,2);
checkAll(-3,-5);
checkAll(0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear otra función

```
function chequearTodo(posX, posY) {
    return (checkearBloque(posX,posY)
         && checkearnota(posX,posY)
         && checkeaArbol(posX,posY)
         && checkeaPoso(posX,posY)
         && checkeacasa(posX,posY)
         && checkeaLago(posX,posY)
         && checkearmaria(posX,posY)
         && checkearPedro(posX,posY)
         && checkearLetrero(posX,posY));
}
```

lo que te permitiría hacer más legible el `switch`:

```
switch(event.which)
{   
    case 119:
        if (chequearTodo(posX, posY + 1) {
        // ....
        }
    break;

    case ...:
        if (chequearTodo(posX + 1, posY) {
        // ....
        }
    break;

    // el resto de casos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estás haciendo un jueguecillo, y lo que quieres hacer es comprobar si se puede mover hacia ese lado, pues bien, lo que suele hacerse es crear un objecto que tenga la propiedad dureza, y del que heredan los demás objetos (en tu caso bloque, nota, árbol, pozo...), y lo que haces es que si las coordenadas a las que vas están ocupadas por un objeto con dureza a true deniegas el movimiento y si la dureza es false lo permites (el muñeco se puede mover encima de ese objeto).